# The declaration of Operator<< overloading does not recognize its definition

Tags: c++, scope

I have the following structure:

```
// [String.h]
namespace ns {
    class String {
            std::wstring m_string;
        public:
            const wchar_t* ToCString() const;
            friend ::std::ostream& operator<<(::std::ostream& os, const String& stringObject);
            // ...
    };
}


// [String.cpp]
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ns::String& stringObject) {
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> conv;
    os << conv.to_bytes(stringObject.ToCString());
    return os;
}
```

The following error occurs:
`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl ns::operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class ns::String const &)" (??6ns@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV12@ABVString@0@@Z) referenced in function _main`

I know when using this way `namespace ns {}` everything will work, but is there another way than the previous way, since this way `ns::method` is not appropriate with the friend method?

Comment: Did you implement the function inside the right namespace?  You don't show a namespace in your cpp file.

Comment: @StephenNewell: In the ".cpp" file I am using this way `ns::method`  I don't use `namespace ns {}` in the ".cpp" file.

Comment: You might want to update your code to match then, since you don't have `ns` anywhere in your cpp code on the question.

Comment: @StephenNewell: But this way `ns::method` is not acceptable from the compiler, because this is a friend function not a member of the class.

Answer (score 2):

Write your implement of `operator<<` in the namespace `ns`. This was compiled successfully in VS2019.

```
// implementation in .cpp file.
namespace ns
{
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ns::String& stringObject)
    {
        std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> conv;
        os << conv.to_bytes(stringObject.ToCString());
        return os;
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding the first problem, it is not a real problem it is just a mistake when copying the code. and the second problem,  in the ".cpp" file I am using this way `ns::method` I don't use` namespace ns {}` in the ".cpp" file.

Comment: @LionKing I was wonder how that typo was not found in IDE and thought it maybe happened while copying and paste your code. I removed the first one.

Comment: @LionKing I tried `ns::method` and `ns::String::method` first time but failed. I guess it's because of `friend` keyword, but I can't be sure and posted other successful code.

Comment: I know when using this way `namespace ns {}` everything will be good, but is there another way than that, since this way `ns::method` is not appropriate with the friend method?

Comment: @LionKing I'm not good enough for the question. Actually I avoid using `friend`, and I prefer declaring operator overloadings as free functions which has showed me no serious problems so far. I hope someone else can answer it.